# VaComm in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

i want to use the Comport in my Delphi program, I am using como send data works well, but problem is with receiving data. When it receive data then the system should call the procedure VaComm1RxChar, but it doesnt. This procedure never run. But even when I check if there are some chars in buffer by function VaComm1.ReadBufUsed it returns me a value, so there must be some received data.

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code, it contains only two:

```
procedure TForm2.VaComm1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var text: string;
begin
   text:=Vacomm1.ReadText;
   Memo1.Lines.Add(text);
   ShowMessage('Some data received!');
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

   Vacomm1.WriteText('Hello');
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Hello');
   sleep(200);
end;
```

Comment: I worked with serial interface over com some years ago. I think, there is no push mechanism. I had to poll for data with a timeout, back then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that some data is received? Have you checked proper data flow with Windows Terminal-like program?

Is port opened?
Check that `Vacomm1.OnRXChar` event property is linked with your `VaComm1RxChar` method
Check that `ceRxChar` is included in `MonitorEvents` property

Comment: The MonitorEvents property is probably missing the ceRxChar bit.

Comment: Yes, when I click on the object VaComm1 I see in the settings that ceRxChar is checked.

Comment: Thank you, the event was checked in properties but the problem was that it wasnt linked with VaComm1RxChar.. SOLVED